# How to create a printing method that doesn't print attributes (without making a copy of the object) in R?

Tags: r, methods, printing, copy

I'm creating a custom S3 object in R, but when I print it the attributes also gets printed. For example:

```r
x <- 1:3
x <- structure(x, class = "myclass")
print(x)
#> [1] 1 2 3
#> attr(,"class")
#> [1] "myclass"
```

Fair enough, I haven't yet added a `print` method. Many answers here in SO and other places recommend removing the attributes from the object, and then printing it, like so (also returning the object invisibly to maintain the `print` original property):

```r
x <- 1:3
x <- structure(x, class = "myclass")

print.myclass <- function(x, ...) {
  print(unclass(x), ...)
  return(invisible(x))
}

print(x)
#> [1] 1 2 3
```

This approach, however, creates a copy of `x`, and I don't want that. We can see that with `tracemem()`:

```r
x <- 1:3
x <- structure(x, class = "myclass")
tracemem(x)
#> [1] "<0x558e1a9adcc8>"

print.myclass <- function(x, ...) {
  print(unclass(x), ...)
  return(invisible(x))
}

print(x)
#> tracemem[0x558e1a9adcc8 -> 0x558e1aa63918]: print print.myclass print
#> [1] 1 2 3
```

The original `print` doesn't create a copy of `x`:

```r
x <- 1:3
x <- structure(x, class = "myclass")
tracemem(x)
#> [1] "<0x557799ebeb88>"

print(x)
#> [1] 1 2 3
#> attr(,"class")
#> [1] "myclass"
```

Hadley suggests, in his Advanced R book, that one could use `NextMethod()` to [prevent creating a copy in a subset method](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/s3.html#nextmethod). I have spent some time thinking on how to prevent creating a copy when printing an S3 object with an attribute, but I couldn't figure out how to do so.

In fact, I just tested printing a `tibble` and a copy is also created:

```r
z <- tibble::tibble(x = 1, y = 2)
tracemem(z)
#> [1] "<0x55e2aa368c48>"

print(z)
#> tracemem[0x55e2aa368c48 -> 0x55e2aa339e48]: lapply tbl_subset_row [.tbl_df [ do.call head.data.frame head as.data.frame tbl_format_setup.tbl tbl_format_setup_ tbl_format_setup format.tbl format writeLines print.tbl
#> # A tibble: 1 x 2
#>       x     y
#>   <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1     1     2
```

But a `data.table` doesn't:

```r
z <- data.table::data.table(x = 1, y = 2)
tracemem(z)
#> [1] "<0x55d64b2bd310>"

print(z)
#>    x y
#> 1: 1 2
```

So I guess that this problem is solvable, but I haven't figured out how...

**EDIT:**

Ok, I did some reading on `print.data.frame` and it solves this problem by converting the `data.frame` to a `matrix` and then printing this matrix. This is a very clever solution, and I guess `data.table` uses something similar.

More generally speaking, however, this wouldn't work for some other type of objects (e.g. those that can't be formatted as a matrix, for example). Take this one:

```r
z <- list(a = data.frame(a = 1, b = 2), b = data.frame(c = 3, d = 4))
z <- structure(z, class = "myotherclass")
tracemem(z)
#> [1] "<0x56298a95fd48>"

print(z)
#> $a
#>   a b
#> 1 1 2
#> 
#> $b
#>   c d
#> 1 3 4
#> 
#> attr(,"class")
#> [1] "myotherclass"

print.myotherclass <- function(x, ...) {
  print(unclass(x), ...)
  return(invisible(x))
}

print(z)
#> tracemem[0x56298a95fd48 -> 0x56298aaa58a8]: print print.myotherclass print
#> $a
#>   a b
#> 1 1 2
#> 
#> $b
#>   c d
#> 1 3 4
```

How'd you do it in this case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about using something like `print(x[seq_along(x)])` in your print method? It avoids the copy it seems and attributes persist.

```
z <- list(a = data.frame(a = 1, b = 2), b = data.frame(c = 3, d = 4))
z <- structure(z, class = "myotherclass")
tracemem(z)

print.myotherclass <- function(x, ...) {
  print(x[seq_along(x)])
  return(invisible(x))
}

y <- print(z)
#> $`a`
#> a b
#> 1 1 2
#> 
#> $b
#> c d
#> 1 3 4

attributes(y)
#> $`names`
#> [1] "a" "b"
#> 
#> $class
#> [1] "myotherclass"
```

Comment: That does the trick! I had thought about something similar, but your answer is way more elegant. I wonder if it is possible to conditionally hide only a few attributes, instead of all of them, but well, you did anwer the question I originally asked!

Comment: I guess you could add a second print statement in the function to show only a subset of the attributes, something like `print(attr(x, 'class'))`. Although that isn't really conditioned on anything.